# What is the best way to store credentials in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, pipeline, credentials

The scenario I am working on needs me to store my ssh key in jenkins to ssh to other servers. My concern is that if I store my keys in the server where jenkins is running will that not compromise my keys and can be used by other users as well?

Comment: Hi @Swaraj, welcome to SO. Ideally if you have have had your ssh key somewhere in a location in the server, then your Jenkins job would use that to ssh into the server and do some tasks. The access itself to the server is provided only to the known people right? so I do not get who are the other users that would concern you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have stored the keys in Jenkins GUI and I am not admin. So my concern is for other non admin users like me logging to the GUI and using my credentials to run the pipeline.